# Closure of $A= (0,1) \cup (1,2)$ vs. Closure of $A = [0,1] \cup \{2\}$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Closure of $A= (0,1) \cup (1,2)$ vs. Closure of $A = [0,1] \cup \{2\}$

I am trying to figure out the difference of the closure of these two sets.

Informally, my definition of closure is the smallest possible closed set that contains $A$.  My professor constantly says that if the set is closed then you are done.  If not fix the parts where it is not closed.  For example on the first set $A$ the problem points are $0$, $1$, and $2$.  So the closure of that set $A$ is $[0,2]$ but for the second set I am thinking that it is already closed? because it's complement is open?

Am I on the right track?

Comment: Yes, the second set is closed, so its closure is itself.

Comment: Everything you said seems right, but it's important to acknowledge the topology of the space you're working in.  $\mathbb{R}$ has numerous topologies defined on it, but if you're working in the Euclidean topology then you're fine.

Comment: Yes. You're doing well.

Comment: I agree with Mnifldz-it's critical in topology to be clear what the topology on the space is. Sets are only open and closed relative to a given topology,that can't be stressed enough.

Comment: We don't talk about the Euclidean Topology but these are in the usual topology

Comment: What would the Interior of $[0,1] \cup \{2\}$ be?

Answer (score 1):

Recall that the topology on $\mathbf{R}$ is generated by finite intervals $(a,b)$, meaning an open set is any set you may form through finite intersection and arbitrary unions of finite intervals $(a,b)$. The second set is closed. To see this, consider its complement, $(-\infty,0)\cup (0,2)\cup(2,\infty)$, which is a union of open sets: a finite open interval, union two intervals that are formed by infinite unions of open sets. The first set is open, but $[0,2]$ closed. Were you to remove any single point from this set it would no longer be closed and so it's the smallest closed set containing $(0,1)\cup(1,2)$, which is to say the closure of $(0,1)\cup(1,2)$.

This really has nothing to do with your problem, but for some reason I think of rubbing a coin with a pen through a piece of paper leaving a print. To (and including) wherever the edge is, is where you're `filling in' when you take closures.

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't comment (low rep), the interior of $A=[0,1]\cup\{2\}$ would be $(0,1)$. Take any $x$ inside $\operatorname{int}A$. $x$ cannot be $0$, $1$ or $2$ since there isn't any $ε>0$ so that 
$(x-ε,x+ε)$ is fully inside $A$. So $x$ belongs to $(0,1)$ and so $\operatorname{int}A$ is inside $(0,1)$. And $B=(\operatorname{int}[0,1])\cup(\operatorname{int}{2})$ is inside $\operatorname{int}A$. But $\operatorname{int}\{2\}$ is the empty space and $\operatorname{int}[0,1]$ is $(0,1)$ and so $(0,1)$ is inside $\operatorname{int}A$. Therefore $\operatorname{int}A=(0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the first set A and the second E, to clarify things-and I assume we're working in the usual topology on **R**. A is a union of 2 open sets and therefore open. The closure by definition is the union of the set A and all it's limit points, denoted A'. (It's not hard to show this is equivalent to your definition-try it.) The limit points of A are 0,1, and 2 since if B is an $\epsilon$ niehborhoods centered at any of these points x=0,1 or 2 then $A - {x} \cap B$ $\neq \emptyset$. So these are the limit points of A and $A \cup A'$ = $(0,1)\cup (1,2) \cup {0}\cup{1} \cup {2}$ = [0,2]. And as said above, any closed set is it's own closure, so E= closure (E).